# In a Firefox Add-on how to resolve the error "window is not defined" when adding an eventlistener to the overall browser window?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, event-listener

I try to add an eventListener to my extension. I want to execute a function everytime a tab is  active (got clicked by the user) or is new loaded.

I tried this:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", checkHost(), false);
```

It gives me the error

> Uncaught Reference Error: window is not defined

It drives me cracy, i can't find examples on the web. Please help me.

Comment: I know nothing about firefox addons, but just a suggestion - you probably don't want `checkHost()`...I think you'd just want `checkHost` (unless `checkHost` returns a function when called). `addEventListener` expects a reference to a function

Comment: I'm guessing you could do what you need with Greasemonkey, by the sound of it.

Comment: I will share this extension with around 60-80 ppl, I won't force them to get greasemonkey first, @lan that's true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via your current status: http://builder.addons.mozilla.org/package/206579/latest

The online builder is an online IDE for developing with the [Addon-SDK](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/), where `window` isn't in global scope -- it's not any specific window.

You can include the [tabs module](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/tabs.html) and listen for ready events or activate (a tab is now focused) events, which may be what you want.

```
let tabs = require('sdk/tabs');
tabs.on('ready', function (tab) {
  console.log(tab.url + ' is ready!');
});
```

Comment: can you please tell me why `browser.tabs` showing browser is undefined?

Answer (score 2):

For those wanting to use the window object, you can create it using this code:

```
var { viewFor } = require("sdk/view/core");
var window = viewFor(require("sdk/windows").browserWindows[0]);
```

This code can be found on MDN at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/windows

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that Firefox extensions do not run in the context of any particular window.  As such, they often do not have the `window` object defined, or it is defined as something which you are not expecting if you are not familiar with writing extension code.  This is particularly true if you are approaching this from the point of view of writing JavaScript for use within an HTML page.  Extensions operate in a significantly larger context which includes the entire browser and all windows and tabs.  Thus, there is no automatically appropriate window to use as the `window` object. In the context of an extension, each HTML page is just a part of the whole.

You can obtain each primary browser window through the use of [nsIWindowMediator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIWindowMediator).  The following function, [from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/How_to_convert_an_overlay_extension_to_restartless#Step_9.3A_bootstrap.js), will run the function you pass to it once for each open window:

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
function forEachOpenWindow(todo)  // Apply a function to all open browser windows
{
    var windows = Services.wm.getEnumerator("navigator:browser");
    while (windows.hasMoreElements())
      todo(windows.getNext().QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMWindow));
}
```

You will often want to find the `window` for the most recent browser/tab which was accessed by the user.  The following code will define and set the `window` variable to the most recently used browser/tab.  It will work either in the Add-on SDK, or in overlay/bootstrap extensions depending on which portion you un-comment.

For more information about using windows in a Firefox extension, you should see [Working with windows in chrome code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Working_with_windows_in_chrome_code).

```
if (window === null || typeof window !== "object") {
    //If you do not already have a window reference, you need to obtain one:
    //  Add a "/" to un-comment the code appropriate for your add-on type.
    /* Add-on SDK:
    var window = require('sdk/window/utils').getMostRecentBrowserWindow();
    //*/
    /* Overlay and bootstrap (from almost any context/scope):
    var window=Components.classes["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"]
                         .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator)
                         .getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser");        
    //*/
}
```

Alternately using [Services.jsm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Services.jsm) to access [nsIWindowMediator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIWindowMediator):

```
/* Overlay and bootstrap:
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
//*/
if (window === null || typeof window !== "object") {
    //If you do not already have a window reference, you need to obtain one:
    //  Add a "/" to un-comment the code appropriate for your add-on type.
    /* Add-on SDK:
    var window = require('sdk/window/utils').getMostRecentBrowserWindow();
    //*/
    /* Overlay and bootstrap (from almost any context/scope):
    var window = Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser");
    //*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the `eventlistener` inside a script referenced in the `browser.xul` overlay:

Try it like this:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {checkHost();}, false);
```

Comment: still, window is not defined..:(

Comment: Are you sure you have a <script> tag with your javascript file inside the overlay ? I just tried this and it works. See [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/On_page_load) for more information.

Comment: Well, i have no overlay. I'm only creating an widget.

Comment: Are you using the addon-sdk?

Comment: No, I'm using the Online Builder: https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/package/206579/latest/